# Which version of the t-test (or other) should I use?

Tags: t-test, nonparametric

UPDATE: I added histrograms and qqplots at the bottom.

A dataset of 1500 scores is close to being normally distributed, but is somewhat pointy, and is right-skewed.  It has a mean of 500, and a standard deviation of 80. (It fails normality tests, such as Shapiro-Wilks an a qqplot.)  The test was given in all 50 states.

Subset A, from Washington, is 100 scores. The histogram shows the distribution is much flatter than a normal distribution, and is right-skewed. (But is still in the bell-shaped class.)
The mean is 600, and the standard deviation is 105.

Subset B, from Oregon, is 140 scores. The histogram shows the distribution is more concentrated around the mean than a normal distribution, and is right-skewed. (But is still in the bell-shaped class.)
The mean is 490, and the standard deviation is 82.

I want to test whether these two "samples" could have been randomly drawn from the nationwide dataset, to show whether there is a significant difference in the states (attributable to state demographics, education level, methodology, etc.). I also want to show whether there is a significance difference between the WA and OR scores.  What tests can I use to show these things?  Can I use Z-scores on these two states?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "The histogram shows the distribution is much flatter than a normal distribution" -- can you clarify what you mean by "flatter" here? e.g. do you mean "nearer to uniform" or do you mean something else? Similarly when you say "The histogram shows the distribution is more concentrated around the mean than a normal distribution," -- these descriptions both sound like you have changes in variance, rather than changes in *shape*.

Comment: @Glen_b --  I added histograms and qqplots of the three datasets.

Comment: I'd describe the top histogram as seeming more sharply-peaked and heavier tailed than normal with a hint of right skew, while the two subsets below it seem rounder/less peaky and also somewhat right skew. However, with the histograms we need some degree of caution in the interpretation because the appearance can be somewhat sensitive to choice of bin-width and bin-origin. On the other hand the vertical compression in those QQ plots make it hard to discern much beyond the right tail being heavier than the left tail.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental normality criterion for productive use of a two-sample t test is not whether
the data are normal, but whether two group means are approximately normal.
Unless skewness of data in one or both groups is extreme and there are pronounced
outliers, sample sizes in the hundreds should be large enough to ensure that
sample means are near enough to normal for the t test to give useful results.

For the test whether WA and OR scores are drawn from populations with equal means, you should use the Welch two-sample t test. Using the Welch test is good general practice, but here the fact that the two sample standard deviations differ is added incentive to use the Welch test.

For the test whether the WA population mean is similar to the mean for the rest of the US, it would be best to test WA scores against US scores from the other 49 states.
For approximate results, it is probably OK to do a one-sample t test of WA scores for $H_0: \mu_{wa} = 500$ vs. $H_1: \mu_{wa} > 500.$ (Similarly for OR vs. the rest of the US, except the alternative should have `<`.)

Addendum: 'Rules' for when it is OK to assume that sample means are
close enough to normal for use in a t test are necessarily vague because
samples can be of so many different shapes and sizes. But a little
experimentation may help you in specific cases.

Below is an investigation supposing that WA scores are something like
scores `x` that I sampled in R to have $n = 100, \bar X = 600,$ and $S = 105,$
and to be somewhat 'flatter' than normal.

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  420.5   512.9   592.6   600.0   682.5   815.2 
sd(x)
[1] 105

hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
rug(x)
```

[image]

A one-sided, one-sample t test with alternative $H_1: \mu > 500$ in R
has P-value near 0, and so strongly rejects $H_0: \mu = 500.$

```
t.test(x, mu=500, alt="greater")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 9.5238, df = 99, p-value = 5.983e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 500
95 percent confidence interval:
 582.5659      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
      600
```

If you doubt that 'data like' those in `x` give rise to a t statistic
that has very nearly Student's t distribution with $\nu=99,$
we can do a re-sampling experiment: Make 100,000 re-samples of size 100
with replacement from among values is `x`, find the t statistic for each re-sample and see how nearly these values follow $\mathsf{T}(99).$ The histogram of the re-sampled t's seems very close to t-distributed. An ECDF plot of the first 5000 values of t seems very close the the CDF this t distribution.
Truncating the simulated t's to 5000 observations (the largest sample
accommodated by the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in R), we see that the K-S test
does not reject the null hypothesis that this is a sample from $\mathsf{T}(99).$$

```
set.seed(1212)
m = 10^5;  t = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m){
 x.re = sample(x,100,rep=T)
 t[i] =(mean(x.re)-600)*10/sd(x.re) }
summary(t)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-5.101901 -0.675910  0.000449 -0.002509  0.683485  4.412280 

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(t, prob=T,br=50,col="skyblue2")
  curve(dt(x,99),add=T,col="red")
  tt = t[1:5000]
plot(ecdf(tt))
 curve(pt(x,99), add=T, lwd=3, lty="dashed", col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

A Kolmogorov-Smirnov test finds that these 5000 values are consistent
with $\mathsf{T}(99).$ [The K-S test statistic $D$ is the maximum vertical discrepancy between the CDF and ECDF, below the resolution of the graph, which is about 0.02.
In R, `ks.test` is limited to 5000 observations.]

```
ks.test(tt, "pt", 99)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  tt   
D = 0.010515, p-value = 0.6381
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: Thanks.  In the 2nd paragraph, are you saying to test WA and OR against each other, without regard to the mean of the nationwide dataset as a whole? It seems the idea is that the population is all scores that could be generated, and that population would be normally distributed, and the nationwide dataset is just another sampling of that.

Comment: No. It seems you suggested three tests WA vs OR, WA vs.US, OR vs. US. Of these WA vs OR makes good sense. But there are many posts on this site deprecating the comparison of a part of a population with its whole. More reasonable comparisons are of the part vs the _remainder_ of the whole. So I suggested WA vs other 49 and OR vs other 49.

Comment: My comment above was only about WA vs. OR.  It appears you are not using the nationwide data (or mean) when comparing those two (or 48 states of the nationwide data), which means WA and OR are being "randomly" drawn from a hypothetical, normally distributed population.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's more like saying it makes more sense to compare Women with Men than to compare Women with Humans.

Comment: So, when comparing a trait of men and women, the population they are drawn from is all humans. So what is the population that the test scores from CA and WA come from? That is what I'm saying. You are using a hypothetical population.

Comment: You said: "*The fundamental criterion for productive use of a two-sample t test is not whether the data are normal, but whether two group means are approximately normal*"-- that the numerator of a t-statistic is approximately normal does not automatically mean that the t-statistic is similarly close to a t-distribution. The t-statistic has a denominator and the derivation of a t-distribution for it relies on both the distribution of the numerator and the denominator (and their independence under normality). We'd need some basis to go from an assertion about the numerator to the whole statistic

Comment: @Glen_b. Thanks for comment. Changed 'criterion' to 'normality criterion'. Of course, your entire comment is relevant---even though elementary books discussing when to use t tests rarely discuss independence of $\bar X$ and $S,$ which is a sure thing only for normal data. // BTW: Wonder what you think about the utility/relevance of the simulation and the end of my Question showing re-sampled $\bar X$'s close to normal. Better to show re-sampled t-statistics close to $\mathsf{T}?$

Comment: @BruceET --  I added histograms and qqplots of the three datasets.

Comment: Thanks for histograms. With sample sizes as large as yours, I see no problem using t tests with such data. (But why PA instead of WA?)

Comment: Oops.  I fixed the labels.  Do you happen to have a reference? I see a couple of articles on the robustness of t-tests, and Type-1 errors, and I'm reading them.

Comment: The robustness of t tests for non-normal data is discussed (with varying degrees of care) in most basic statistics texts. Sample size 30 is too heavily stressed; for some non-normal dist'ns (e.g, exponential) 30 is not nearly enough and for others (e.g., uniform) more than enough. Careful discussions, including independence of $\bar X$ and $S$ and actual effect on t statistic (as in @Glen_b's Comment above) are regrettably rare. Have seen no recent papers on robustness of t; there may be some older ones. Will look, and maybe others on this site already have references at hand.

Comment: "discussed (with varying degrees of care) in most basic statistics texts" -- yes, lots talk about it but from what I've seen about 90% of the texts that do so across a range of disciplines make statements that are flat out wrong; most of the rest say things that are more or less true but the justification offered is often inadequate and the advice about when to use it of little practical use (advice that's not clearly wrong amounting to "it works when it works"). However, that's a slightly different issue to the part right at the top of your answer that only the numerator is of consequence...

Comment: ... People usually attempt to invoke (/imply) an argument from the CLT in doing that, but that only justifies treating the numerator as close to normal for some large (but not fixed) n; if we also invoke Slutsky for the denominator we get that the statistic is asymptotic-normal. More than that is required to claim we have a t-distribution for a t-statistic (or even to just say "the t-approximation will be better than the justifiable normal approximation"). In practice the t is often a perfectly reasonable approximation but the argument for it is usually based on simulation and is case-by-case

Comment: Do we even have a good general justification for using the $t$ distribution as an approximation rather than the normal beyond "well, it works ... when it works, but it often looks to be okay in practice"? Few books say anything as explicitly weak as that but do we really have a better justification to offer? You're right that there are previous posts on this topic and extensive discussions in comments -- I've read many answers here on site (and written quite a number myself) but have not seen much that would really count as supplying much beyond that sort of vague handwaving.

Comment: @Glen_b. I have changed the last part of my Answer to show one of the 'case-by-case` simulations you mention. It is based on re-sampled t statistics from the data `x`. I hope it a step beyond waving arms and appealing only to the CLT.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, this would be an addendum to my previous answer. However, it is as much about my discussion in Comments with @Glen_b as it is about OP's Question.

A discussion about the robustness of t tests against some kinds of
non-normal data often begins by looking at normal probability plots and
investigating loss of power for various non-normal distributional shapes.
(See, recent editions of Ott & Longnecker: *Intro. to Stat. Methods and Data Analysis,* Ch 5, for one such approach.) Other accounts say that the CLT
may make sample means nearly normal and normality of the data overall
may not be so important. Some of these include bogus statements about
20 or 30 observations being some sort of magic guarantee that a t test
will be robust. Seldom mentioned is @Glen-b's point that $\bar X$ and $S$ need to be independent in order for the t statistic to have a Student's t distribution.

If one is to complain about careless promises of robustness, it seems
a good idea to have at least one specific problematic case in mind.
An exponential sample of size above 30 seemed a likely candidate, so
that is were I begin.

Perhaps the first concrete warning sign is that, for such samples, t tests at the intended 5% level do not actually have significance level 5%. More like 7%.

```
set.seed(1234)
pv=replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(35),mu=1)$p.val)
mean(pv < 0.05)
[1] 0.06852
```

Consider, specifically, this sample `y` of size $n=35$  with $\bar Y = 0.968$ from $\mathsf{Exp}(1).$

```
set.seed(1235)
y = rexp(35)
mean(y)
[1] 0.9675814
```

Multiple t statistics, intended to test $H_0: \mu=1$ vs. $H_1:\mu\ne 1,$ can be
simulated by re-sampling from `y` as follows:

```
set.seed(1236)
m = 10^5;  t = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
  y.re = sample(y,35,rep=T)
  t[i] = (mean(y.re)-mean(y))*sqrt(35)/sd(y.re) }
summary(t)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-10.02747  -0.89537  -0.07087  -0.27109   0.57515   3.10906
```

The distribution of these values `t` is not distributed as $\mathsf{T}(\nu=35).$ The histogram does match the appropriate t density, and
the ECDF of the first 5000 values does not match the appropriate CDF.

[image]

And a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on the first 5000 `t`s strongly rejects $\mathsf{T}(\nu=35)$ as the
correct distribution of the purported t statistics.

```
ks.test(tt, "pt", 34)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  tt
D = 0.071059, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The averages $\bar Y$ of samples of size 35 from $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ are
distributed as $\mathsf{Gamma}(35,35)$ (blue density), not
exactly normal (red dots). More seriously, the sample means and standard
deviations are not independent, so 't statistics' cannot have a t
distribution. (In particular for $X_i > 0,$ one has $\bar Y \ge S/\sqrt{n},$
so no point can lie above the line $S = \sqrt{n}\,\bar Y.)$

[image]

```
set.seed(1237);  m = 50000;  n = 35
v = rexp(m*n);  DAT = matrix(v, nrow=m)
a = rowMeans(DAT);  s = apply(DAT, 1, sd)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hdr="Averages of Exponential Sample Not Normal"
 hist(a, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
  curve(dgamma(x,35,35), add=T, col="blue", lwd=2)
  curve(dnorm(x,mean(a),sd(a)), add=T, col="red", 
        lty="dotted", lwd=2)
hdr="Averages and SDs of Exp Samples Not Indep"
 plot(a,s, pch=".",main=hdr)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

*Note:* An exact test for means of exponential samples, based on $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=35, 
\mathrm{rate}=35),$ is available.